# php preg_replace \n

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to double escape \n into \\n. The string is echoed and passed to client side javascript code which retrieves the data by doing an eval. I have tried doing `preg_replace('/\\/', 'blah', $string)`, which returns an empty string. However, when I used `preg_replace('/\n/', 'blah', $string)`, it worked. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest using `json_encode()` for the string escaping. Or maybe even just `addslashes()` might do.

Comment: I think this might be the one case *ever* where `addslashes` is a right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `str_replace("\n", "\\n", $string)`?

Comment: That'd replace a literal newline with the 3-char escaped version. I think the op wants to take a literal `\n` 2-char string and make it 3-char.

Comment: Then it would be `str_replace("\\n", "\\\\n", $string)` I guess, but the question is not perfectly clear to me..

Comment: Well, I also want any kind of backslash to be escaped, as it causes an error in the eval(). More ideas?